# Assign index # according to current section

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

Say I have a total width of 585px. And I wanted to divide the space into equal sections and assign each an index value within position. I could do something like this if I had lets say 6 sections: (assigned by total width / number of sections)

```
    //Set up elements with variables
            this.sliderContent = config.sliderContent;
            this.sectionsWrap = config.sectionsWrap;

            //Selects <a>
            this.sectionsLinks = this.sectionsWrap.children().children();

            //Create drag handle
            this.sectionsWrap.parent().append($(document.createElement("div")).addClass("handle-containment")
                                      .append($(document.createElement("a")).addClass("handle ui-corner-all").text("DRAG")));

            //Select handle
            this.sliderHandle = $(".handle");

var left = ui.position.left,
    position = [];

var position = ((left >= 0 && left <= 80) ? [0, 1] :
    ((left >= 81 && left <= 198) ? [117, 2] :
    ((left >= 199 && left <= 315) ? [234, 3] :
    ((left >= 316 && left <= 430) ? [351, 4] :
    ((left >= 431 && left <= 548) ? [468, 5] :
    ((left >= 549) ? [585, 6] : [] ) ) ) ) ) );

        if (position.length) {
            $(".handle").animate({
                left : position[0]
            }, 400);
            Slider.contentTransitions(position);
        }
```

But what if I had an x number of sections. These sections are just elements like

```
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
```

Or

```
<div><a></a></div>
<div><a></a></div>
<div><a></a></div>
<div><a></a></div>
```

How would I divide the total of 585px and classify the index in position according to the current left value of the `.handle` element? I can know where the drag handle is by using `ui.position.left`, what I want is to be able to set an index for each element and be able to animate handle depending on where the handle is within the indexed elements. Since each element is indexed I later call a transition method and pass in the current index # to be displayed. The code I show above works, but isn't really efficient. I also need to account for the width of the handle to fit the section width. http://jsfiddle.net/yfqhV/1/

[image: Example of what I made]

Comment: how do you arrive at positions of 0/81/199/... for checking where left is?

Comment: @Raad The first one was so that the handle would line up, the 199 is 81 + 117 + 1px border; the others are all 117 added to the previous left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there is a slight inconsistency in the difference between the range figures in the question, which makes it hard to algorithmise [ my *made-up-word de jour* =) ] this exactly:

- 81 to 199 = 118
- 199 to 316 = 117
- 316 to 431 = 115
- 431 to 518 = 118

If you can adjust for that, I have a solution - it's not especially clever JavaScript, so there may well be better ways to do this (SO JS people, feel free to educate me!) but it works.

First we need a function to find the index of an array range, a given value falls within (this replaces your nested if-else shorthands), then we have a function to set up the positional arrays, and finally we can do a range search and return the corresponding array of values.

This solution should dynamically deal with a varying number of sections, as long as this line:

```
var len = $("#sectionContainer").children().length;
```

is adjusted accordingly. The only other values that may need adjusting are:

```
    var totalWidth = 585;
    var xPos = 81;
```

although you could set them if you have elements you can draw the values from, making it even more of a dynamic solution.

```
/**
 * function to find the index of an array element where a given value falls
 * between the range of values defined by array[index] and array[index+1]
 */
function findInRangeArray(arr, val){
  for (var n = 0; n < arr.length-1; n++){

      if ((val >= arr[n]) && (val < (arr[n+1]))) {
          break;
      }
  }
  return n;
}

/**
 * function to set up arrays containing positional values
 */
function initPositionArrays() {
    posArray = [];
    leftPosArray = [];

    var totalWidth = 585;
    var xPos = 81;

    var len = $("#sectionContainer").children().length;
    var unit = totalWidth/(len - 1);

    for (var i=1; i<=len; i++) {
      pos = unit*(i-1);
      posArray.push([Math.round(pos), i]);
      xMin = (i >= 2 ? (i==2 ? xPos : leftPosArray[i-2] + posArray[1][0]) : 0);
      leftPosArray.push(Math.round(xMin));
    }
}

var left = ui.position.left;

initPositionArrays();

// find which index of "leftPosArray" range that "left" falls within
foundPos = findInRangeArray(leftPosArray, left);
var position = posArray[foundPos];

if (position.length) {
  $(".handle").animate({
    left : position[0]
  }, 400);
  Slider.contentTransitions(position);
}
```

I've set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raad/AshG5/7/) to illustrate.

Enjoy!

---

**Edit**

I've looked at @JonnySooter s own answer, and whilst it calculates the positioning correctly, it won't deal with a variable number of sections.

To get it to work with *any* number of sections, the `handleContainment` div (that is created on-the-fly) needs to have it's width set dynamically (via inline styling).
This is calculated by multiplying the number of sections by the width of each section (which is actually the same as the width of the slider).
This is all done after creating the handle so that the width can be extracted from the "handle" css class, meaning a change to the width of the handle will cascade into the routine when applied at the css level.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raad/DfM5F/48/) where the number of sections can be altered and the slider behaves properly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've been working on a separate solution and have set an answer. If you can, compare the two and see if you have any other suggestions for me. If so, I could accept your answer.

Comment: Awesome possum! I like it and have accepted as an answer. I appreciate the time you've taken to go through this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numSections = // ...;
var totalWidth = // ...;
var sectionWidth = totalWidth / numSections;
var index = Math.floor($(".handle").position().left / sectionWidth);
var leftPosition = index * sectionWidth;
var rightPosition = leftPosition + sectionWidth - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

I worked on trying to find a solution myself and this is what I came up with:

```
function( event, ui ) {
    var left = ui.position.left, //Get the current position of the handle
        self = Slider, //Set to the Slider object cus func is a callback
        position = 1;
        sections_count = self.sectionsLinks.length, //Count the sections
        section_position = Math.floor(self.sectionsWrap.width() / sections_count); //Set width of each section according to total width and section count

    left = Math.round(left / section_position); //Set the index
    position = (left * section_position); //Set the left ammount

    if(position < section_position){ //If handle is dropped in the first section
        position = 0.1; //Set the distance to animate
        left = 0; //Set index to first section
    }

    if (position.length) {
        $(this).animate({
            left : position //Animate according to distance
        }, 200);
        left = left += 1; //Add one to the index so that I can use the nth() child selector later.
        self.contentTransitions(left);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a couple of things - the above function is missing a name, and do you have an example of the html for the slider menu?

Comment: The HTML that is in the question is the basic template. I have html that I'm using but I want it to be variable. I'll update the question.

Comment: Also the function is a callback of the handle moving event, so it doesn't need a name.

Comment: Doh! Yes, of course it doesn't. However, the code you posted doesn't seem to match up with the html snippet (e.g. no `sectionLinks`, or `sectionsWrap`). Any chance you can jsFiddle what you have working?

Comment: Doh![2] Should have made that fiddle like 10 years ago. Anyways here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/yfqhV/1/